# drop down list via my sql

Tags: php, mysql, html

i have one combo box in one html page another page i want to call the database.in the database select the customer name these names are diaplayed in combo box respectively.please the code for me.

Comment: We won't do it for you, show us what you have got so far and someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

```
<?php 
$db_name = "db";
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT customer_name,id from customers ORDER BY customer_name desc";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1){
    $form = '<form method="POST" action="">
    <p>Customer name:<select size="1" name="customer">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $form .='<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.ucwords($row['customer_name']).'</option>';
    }
    $form .=' </select></p><p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>';
}
echo $form;
?>
```